# Image layers cufon jquery php saving the resulting composite?

Tags: php, jquery, html, image-manipulation, imagemagick

This question is a bit open at the moment as I'm not sure the idea is even possible.

So far I've loaded an image from a url, and then used jQuery UI draggable feature to allow the user to drag html text (which has been replaced using cufon font replacement) over the top of the image.

The major step (which is what my question relates to) is being able to take the image and text layered over the top of the image, and save the result, either to the server, or potentially offer the option to save the altered image to the user's HD, or what would also be useful is to upload to facebook using the facebook API, but this is something I know is possible.

It all hangs on whether it's even possible to achieve the first step, which is to save the image and layered text as a combined image?

I wonder if there is a PHP/jQuery solution that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have an internal URL that outputs the final image using jQuery and PHP, then take a screenshot using [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) of that page. You should know the dimensions etc., so you'll be able to crop down the resulting screenshot to just the region you're looking for.

Comment: if I've understood correctly, the first bit could perhaps be achieved by using jquery to access the entire $(body).html() into a string, and post it back to the server using ajax, where it will store the resulting html (minus script tags) in a unique html file. Then the user is redirected to a new page, where it'll call webkit2png on that re-generated html file to generate/crop the image, and then display the resulting image to the user, where they can then save it locally, post it to facebook, or perhaps access it on the server at a later date.  you've given me something to think about, ta.